# history.push is not working after using history.block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to show a message when user try to leave current page, so I am using history.block like this:

```
    import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
    
    
    const ProfilerCreate = ({ pageType }) => {
    const history = useHistory();
    const [isDisabled, setIsDisabled] = useState(true);
    const [openModalUnsave, setOpenModalUnsave] = useState(false);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        history.block(validateChange);
     }, []
    );
    
    //Function to validate changes and open modal
      function validateChange(txt) {
        if (!isDisabled) {
          toggleModalUnsave();
          return false;
        }
      }

//Function to open or close modal
  function toggleModalUnsave() {
    setOpenModalUnsave(!openModalUnsave);
  }

//Function to return landing page
  function returnPage() {
    history.push("/");
  }
    
    return (
...
<div style={{ display: "none" }}>
        <Modal
          id="myModal"
          heading="You have unsaved changes"
          description="Do you want to save or discard them?"
          isOpen={openModalUnsave}
          onRequestClose={(detail) => toggleModalUnsave()}
          actionsRight={
            <>
              <Button display="text" onClick={() => returnPage()}>
                Discard
              </Button>
              <Button
                display="primary"
                onClick={(evt) => saveAudienceData(evt)}
              >
                Save and exit
              </Button>
            </>
          }
        >
          <p>Modal Children</p>
        </Modal>
      </div>
);
    
    export default ProfilerCreate;
```

when it is detecting unsaved changes, it shows a modal with a warning and two buttons, one for save and the other for discard, when the user hit discard button it should return to home page, but `history.push` is not working.

I tried to find the solution or I don't know if I am using the `history.block` in a wrong way.

I hope that you can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the `unblock()` method in `validateChange(txt)`